# Bios not showing on external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, bios

When I try to get into bios my monitor doesn't display any image on any of my 2 monitors. My PC does keep running but nothing happens after that. I tried taking out the CMOS battery and shorting the pins. I also tried getting into bios trough the advanced options tab but that gave the same result. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

I have a

- MSI MAG B550 TOMAHAWK,
- AMD Ryzen 5 5600X,
- AMD Radeon RX 7600
- 2X16 GB 3200MHz RAM from Corsair

Comment: Try with only one monitor...

Answer (score -1):

We can't know what is the specific problem, but it's possible
that something is wrong with the BIOS/UEFI.

I suggest to update your BIOS with the
[AMI BIOS latest version](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-B550-TOMAHAWK/support),
even if you currently have already this same version.
Re-flashing will reset the BIOS to generic values, so you will have
to redo any settings that you have changed.

I suggest to ensure you have good backups before starting and not
to interrupt the flash for any reason whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this!

Comment: To the serial downvoter that just passed here : I think your attitude is unsuitable.